# Can I use DBMS_METADATA to strip off the SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP from a DDL?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I would like to obtain the DDL of a table and create another one from it. Currently I have something like this:

```
 v_stmt := 'select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(''TABLE'', ''' || original_table || ''') from dual';
 execute immediate v_stmt into v_stmt ;
 v_stmt := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_stmt, '(' || original_table || ')', new_table, 1, 1);
 execute immediate v_stmt;
```

The current table has SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP generated. I do not want this, or rather when I try to create I face the below error.

```
ORA-30567: name already used by an existing log group
```

How do I get rid of the SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP? Is it possible to use something like below or there is some other solution?

```
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PARTITIONING',false);
```

I think I can also use REGEXP_REPLACE but I don't know how to go about it either.

For  reference the generated statement contains something like below:

```
...
 SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "SCHEM_TAB0123434" ("CUSTOMERKEY", "VALID", "VERSION", "WHENMODIFIED") ALWAYS, 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM won't help here.
You can try with REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
`v_stmt := regexp_replace(v_stmt, ',\s*supplemental\s+log\s+group\s+"[^"]+"\s*\("[^"]+"(,\s*"[^"]+")*\)\s*always\s*', '',1, 1,'i');`
```

Comment: Thank you, what does the 'i' signifies in the above statement?

Comment: @pna - that the match is case-insensitive.

Comment: I confirm, the three parameters after replacement string `''` are position, occurence, and regex matching mode, the latter was `'i'`(case insensitive) for convenience.

Comment: Thank you everyone. However this only removes the first occurence of the supplemental log group. I would like to remove all occurences.

Comment: @pna I expected you would accept Alex's answer, are you sure?

Comment: Alex's Answer is great, however I found out that the existing code already uses REGEXP_REPLACE in few other places. So it would be easier for me to continue on that line. I assume if I replace the 3rd parameter with 0 it will replace all occurrences?

Comment: Oh one more thing, the replace string leaves out a , at the end. So the result ends up with few commas at the end. I just added a comma after always in the syntax to fix it.

Comment: Yes, occurrence=0 will replace all occurences. I don't quite get what's wrong with a comma. The leading `,\s*` in the regex should have already taken care of them, since every `supplemental` clause has only one comma before it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be able to get rid of it entirely, but you could split the supplemental logging clauses out into separate statements and skip them, if you use different `dbms_metadata` subprograms.

The `fetch_ddl` procedure gives you a nested table of individual DDL statements; and you can combine that with a `set_transform_param()` call to pull constraints out as `alter` statements - which also applies to the supplemental log clause. You can also change the table name as part of the fetch call, rather than manually replacing it later, with `set_remap_param()`.

If I create a dummy table with supplemental logging:

```
create table t42 (
  id number,
  log_this varchar2(10),
  constraint pk_t42 primary key (id),
  supplemental log group t42_log_group (log_this) always
);
```

then I can open a context handle, apply a filter for the table name, and a transform; then loop over the DDL and choose what to use and what to skip:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
  l_original_table user_tables.table_name%type := 'T42';
  l_new_table user_tables.table_name%type := 'NEW_T42';

  l_context pls_integer;
  l_modify pls_integer;
  l_transform pls_integer;
  l_ddls sys.ku$_ddls;
  l_ddl clob;
begin
  l_context := dbms_metadata.open('TABLE');
  -- to look for the specific table you are interested in
  dbms_metadata.set_filter(l_context, 'NAME', l_original_table);

  l_modify := dbms_metadata.add_transform(l_context, 'MODIFY');
  -- to change the table name in the generated DDL
  dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(l_modify, 'REMAP_NAME', l_original_table, l_new_table,
    'TABLE');

  l_transform := dbms_metadata.add_transform(l_context, 'DDL');
  -- for brevity
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(l_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
  -- to split constraints and supplemental logging into separtate DDLs
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(l_transform, 'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', true);

  l_ddls := dbms_metadata.fetch_ddl(l_context);

  for i in l_ddls.first..l_ddls.last loop
    l_ddl := l_ddls(i).ddltext;
    if dbms_lob.instr(l_ddl, 'SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP') > 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('Skipping DDL: ' || dbms_lob.substr(l_ddl, 4000, 1));
      continue;
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line('Using DDL: ' || dbms_lob.substr(l_ddl, 4000, 1));
    dbms_output.new_line;

    -- execute immediate l_ddl;
  end loop;

  dbms_metadata.close(l_context);
end;
/
```

which for that dummy table shows:

```
Using DDL: CREATE TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."NEW_T42" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "LOG_THIS" VARCHAR2(10)
   ) 

Using DDL: 
  ALTER TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."NEW_T42" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_T42" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE

Skipping DDL: 
  ALTER TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."NEW_T42" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "T42_LOG_GROUP" ("LOG_THIS") ALWAYS


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The base `create table` is kept, along with any other statements except those matching the `'SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP'` string.

In this case my PK constraint name is also going to be a problem - the first `create` DDL will run OK with `execute immediate` uncommented, but the `alter` that isn't currently being skipped will get ORA-02264. If you have a sensible naming convention you can add additional `set_remap_param` calls to change those too, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I was expecting. Thank you for the detailed answer.